# Changing http-requests conditionally

Tags: typescript, angular-2+, rxjs

I'm new to RXJS and I have a working piece of code for http-request and subscribing to Observables from a shared service in Angular. This works, but I'd want to get rid of the nested subscriptions, which I know is probably very possible with RXJS operators, but I haven't figured out how. The usage of `flatMap` in the nested request wouldn't be necessary, as the second nested request isn't dependable on the first.

```
  this.sub = this.service.isPending$
    .subscribe(data => {
      if(data) { // gives boolean
        this.service.getPending()
          .subscribe((data:Offer) => this.offer = data)
      } else {
        this.sub2 = this.service.amount$
        .flatMap((data: Amount) => {
          this.amount = data;
          return this.service.getOffer()
        })
        .subscribe((data: Offer) => {
          this.offer = data;
        })
      }
    })
```

How would I go about cleaning this code up? I'm using RXJS: "^5.0.1"

Answer (score 1):

## On Observables

My personal preference is to have as few `Subscription` objects and `subscribe()` invocations as possible. If I don't have mistakes in the refactored code, you can achieve a single `subscribe()` which does the same things as your code. I also got rid of `sub2`.

```
this.offerSubscription = this.service
    .isPending$
    .flatMap(data => {
        this.amount = null;
        const offerObservable = data ?
            this.service.getPending() :
            this.service
                .amount$
                .flatMap((data: Amount) => {
                    this.amount = data;
                    return this.service.getOffer();
                });
        return offerObservable;
    })
    .subscribe((offer: Offer) => this.offer = offer);
```

## On TypeScript

`sub`, `sub2`, `isPending$` and `data` are pretty bad names because they don't describe the entities they hold. I recommend changing them.

At the bare minimum, specify the type of the input parameter in your arrow function to make the code more readable: `(data: Offer) => {...}` or better `(receivedOffer: Offer) => { ... }`.

Comment: Specifying the type of a callback parameter is very much like an implicit type assertion and masks the  introduction of `any`.